# Import Neo4J API in Netbeans

Tags: java, api, import, neo4j

For a project I am building a Java GUI from which queries can be sent to Neo4j, to make it easier to do particular analyses. To get this all working, I have downloaded a .jar folder containing all relevant classes (neo4j-javadocs-2.1.7-javadoc.jar). I have loaded the library through the project->properties->libraries->Add JAR, but I can't seem to import the classes I want to use in my GUI (neither automatically nor manually).

I am dabbling in Java, so it is probably a basic oversight that I am making, but with the help from tutorials online and trying different commands (like entering the path of the .jar file) I can't get it working. One of these tutorials is specific on the Neo4j library, so I am very confused. That tutorial is written for Eclipse, instead of NetBeans which I am working with, but as far as my knowledge goes that shouldn't matter for the commands

I don't have enough reputation to post direct images, but this link contains a screenshot. If more information is required, let me know. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUytK.png

Additionally, when I normally add a class that is not imported, there is an automatic function to import the class. This option is missing for my specific class, so maybe I added the library in an incorrect way?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeDX4.png

Edit: Issue resolved thanks to a colleague that came in. Apparently I loaded the Javadoc where I should have loaded to individual classes from the lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

**It really should work.**

1. Try to save all changes. NetBeans reparses the classes when you save them.
2. Try to build your project manually from command line using Ant build script

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaction. I saved and restarted, but the error seems to persist in the same way

Answer (score 0):

Use Maven, Ivy or Gradle for Dependency Management then you can depend on the Neo4j artifacts.

For sending queries to the server you actually don't need Neo4j artifacts.

You can also use the JDBC driver, see http://neo4j.com/developer/java